# How can I fit a bigger rear tyre when limited by the front derailleur?

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur-front

I've recently bought a hardtail, just an entry-level bike, but I've only got entry-level skills.  The tyres it came with are WTB Nano 2.1". They aren't exactly ideal for the sort of conditions we have in the UK in winter (lots of deep mud, wet tree roots, muddy rocks etc.) and I'd like to fit something (i) knobblier and (ii) a little wider.

At the front this is easy, something like a Maxxis Shorty 2.3" or Magic Mary  would easily fit.  At the back, there's also plenty of room *except behind the front derailleur*

[image: 3mm clearance between front derailleur and back tyre]

where there's about 3 mm (and that filled up with mud today)

There are 2" tyres for mud, but they're reputed to have a harsh ride on anything else, and not grip well on wet rock/tree roots -- something I need at my skill level as my lines aren't up to much and I don't always carry enough speed.

This is the only bike I've owned with a top-pull FD.  And I can see why they've used one rather than have cables under the BB getting coated in mud and even bashed.  But it takes up much more room than any of the bottom-pull FD's I've got.  Is it because it's a cheap FD? Because it's a triple? It's an Altus 3×9 drivetrain.

*Is there an upgrade that would gain me a few mm?*

---

As an aside: I picked it up in a hurry, lightly used/ex-rental and without a test ride, for around half the shop price. I'm happy with it apart from this, and assumed that I might upgrade consumables (perhaps as they wear out). I looked at the specs in detail to be sure the fundamentals were there, but is there any way I could have spotted this?

Comment: Are you sure the chain stay clearance is enough for wider tires, especially in the mud?

Comment: Many MTB bikes have down-pull FDs, I have two such setups. It is not such a big deal with mud and bashing them. Rock strikes target the big chainring instead; as of mud, it is everywhere in any case. However, there is always a conflict between having desirable short chainstay and keeping compatibility with knobby tyres.

Comment: @mattnz there's bags of room there: around 12mm.  And if I go to ~2.3" there's a lot of choice of good tyres, I'd still have quite a few mm even to the knobs.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov that's a good point (especially about the chainrings protecting the cable.  I wonder how hard it would be to reroute the cable.  Perhaps I could swap with my hybrid for a test.

Comment: Honestly, ride the bike as-is.  Its an entry level bike, and you claim to have entry level skills.  Work on your skills and then upgrade the bike to what you want in a couple years.  At this point, spending money on a new bike is very fast way to empty the pocketbook.

Comment: @Criggie your point is good, but taking it literally I might as well get rid of the bike today. If I restrict riding to when the existing tyres are suitable, I just won't get out on it enough to build the skills. If I leave the mechanicals alone and upgrade the front tyre I get better control, so that might be an option. Tyres are consumables after all, and not expensive. I've come to expect that they need optimising after buying a bike. Spinning to a halt on muddy climbs is annoying but tolerable.

Comment: @Criggie on re-reading my last comment it might come across as a bit grumpy at the start.  It's not meant to be.

Comment: @ChrisH not at all.  I still ride an 18 kilo steel rigid MTB, and on the flat/doubletrack I can keep up with the squishy bikes fine.  For a straight climb/grind they're pretty similar too.  Lets not mention single track or anything technical or unpaved downhills.

Comment: @Criggie I take the tourer (very close to a CX bike) over quite rough tracks, so the MTB is mainly for single-track etc., or very muddy conditions.

Comment: You can always go knobbier without going wider! 2.1" is actually very wide, it's just not fat bike wide. Doing something like a plus bike conversion would probably not be suitable, but you could probably do a 1x conversion for under $100 if it's very important to you to go wider

Comment: @BEVR1337 and I think I probably will.  But I'm likely to have to go down to 2" to make sure there's room for the knobs.

Comment: As I've bumped this with my edits: If anyone wants to post a "make the best job of what you've got" answer I'll probably accept it.

Comment: On re-reading, a 1x conversion is probably your answer.  However keep the parts aside for later refitting if you choose to, or helps with resale if you move it on.  The easiest conversion will be remove the front mech and its wire, and you could remove the left hand shifter from the bars or leave it there should the grips be too hard to remove.  Extra expense if you buy a new narrow-wide chainring - it might be good enough to just run on an existing chainring with no mech.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a larger tire on the front and don't worry about running a larger tire on the rear.

Back when North Shore BC riding was just starting to take off (i.e., 1990s) we often did this setup as we were equipment limited. At the time the "thinking" was that it was bizarre ride a tire bigger than a 2.0 anything but a dedicated race downhill bike. So we would often swap a fork and run bigger rubber up front as there was clearance issues in the rear. Now  25 years later and anything less than 2.3 is pretty much considered anemic for most riding.

Anyway, the mismatch tire size works fine. The front is where you are often traction limited as you brake and steer with this tire.  A small rear tire may mean a bit harsher ride (i.e., higher pressure with all other things equal) and a tad less traction, but you can afford this compromise on the rear.

Plus, one tire is cheaper than two, and if any one asks just tell them the setup is more aero (#AeroIsEverything - /sarcasm).

Comment: I'll probably upgrade the back as well, within the limitations I've got, but only after trying it with something better at the front only. (I have access to a good range without delivery fees so I don't waste postage costs).

Answer (score 7):

Use a side swing derailleur such as this one: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-m3100/FD-M3100-M.html

This eliminates the linkage behind the seat tube, giving you more clearance. It mounts via a normal band clamp. Versions are also available for E-type and direct mounts.

Some of Shimano’s pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly not available in 3x9 by the look of things, though that's [not insurmountable](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/42782/7309).  In the meantime I've upgraded in the space available, but if I hadn't bought the tyres I might have taken up your suggestion

Comment: @ChrisH The model I linked to says 2x9 in the title, but 3x9 throughout the description. You have a fifty fifty chance :)

Comment: I'd trust the specs table over the title (that led to immediate rejection and looking at the whole range of side swing FDs - none of which has 3x9 in the title).  Also FD-M3120-M is consistently 2x9 and otherwise identical.  But something about that part attracts dodgy descriptions - someone on Amazon feels the need to specify it's unisex - it's out of stock so I'd have to settle for a gendered mechanism.

Comment: I see both [Shimano](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-m3100/FD-M3100-M.html) and [SJS](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/derailleurs-front/shimano-alivio-fdm3100m-9-speed-triple-front-derailleur-side-swing-mid-clamp/) (who I'd probably buy from) now consistently say 3×9

Answer (score 7):

The option I took in the end worked really rather well - I upgraded the front tyre from 2.1" to 2.25" (Nobby Nic) and kept the back at 2.1" with considerably more tread (Rapid Rob) for trail centre and winter use.  Handling on mud and wet roots/rocks is much improved (at the expense of heavier going on road, but I can refit the WTB Nanos for use in the dry).  The rear is perhaps slightly more prone to clogging with very sticky mud, due to the bigger tread,  but that might mean hooking the mud out one extra time on a long ride.

Getting too hung up on width may be a mistake.

Comment: When the Rob wears out i'd suggest trying a Rocket Ron in 2.1. That's a very popular tyre with XC racers in wet/muddy conditions.  And i made the same mistake with my thoughts on width as a beginner mountain biker.  The reality is a narrow tyre cuts through the mud better rather than floating on top, and grip levels on rocks/roots are largely down to rubber compound and low tyre pressure rather than volume and/or tread pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Easy and cheap option - remove FD (change chain ring by hand if needed). Put it back on for summer riding.

More expensive - Go to a full 1x - cost is the only limiting factor

As its disk brakes, you could install a 27.5" rear wheel with a small change to bike geometry (this will help if chain stay clearance is too small on 29" rim).

In all honesty, I suspect your fighting a loosing battle where you will waste a lot of money on a compromise. Be careful listening to the advice of 'expert's who ride $5K bikes, its easy to criticize and suggest improvements when its not your money.

Comment: I like the 27.5 idea, and that's at a price point I could test.  I'm likely to do much of my off-road riding in winter as there are so many more road rides to take up my time in summer, so I'm not sure about a summer-only FD.  Your last paragraph makes a lot of sense, but I have to make the most of this bike for the time being, so it may well be a matter of choosing a compromise -- and not an expensive one.

Comment: Good point about 27.5" tyres. As for going 1x, it can be relatively cheap with a bit of creativity, no need to grab a SRAM Eagle groupset.

Comment: Consider 27 Plus sizes - closer to the 29" diameter. Something like a  Magic Mary which comes in 2.4", 2.6" and 2.8"

Answer (score 1):

There are several options that stem from the idea "Something cannot hinder you if it is not there", namely the FD. Specifically, you can go the ways of 1x or single speed.

Both variants assume you remove all the machinery related to the front shifting (== bonus weight savings!) and leave the single front chainring. For MTB applications the lowest teeth count you can have on the alivio spider is most likely 32t, and that is what I recommend.

The rear derailleur you have is not optimal for achieving a wide ratio range, as 9 speed cassettes are not that wide and will never be. Now even a 10 speed Shimano deore cassette can be had with range 11-42 teeth, and that is just fine for a casual off road adventurer. With 9 speeds (11-34 teeth range) in the back and 32 teeth at the front, one might sometimes feel out of range, but even this setup might be fine on flatter terrains.

One can choose to throw all this gearing bullshit away and go boldly with single speed.  Rear hub conversion kits (a cog, cassette spacers and a chain tensioner) are cheap. More weight savings, no thought power wasted on choosing the right gearing because you are always in the wrong gear, and more fun on descents. On climbs, not so much.

Another crazy idea is to cut some knobs of the rear tyre. There are in fact MTB tyres that are meant to be trimmed by users to their liking, and dedicated tools to do that. The drawback is obviously losing some traction in situations when the removed knobs would have been working.

Finally, moving the rear wheel farther back would be the easiest solution. This is what I actually resorted to when I faced the same issue on my fatbike, because its frame was designed as a multipurpose one. But it requires sliding rear dropouts, which are not super common on MTBs with derailleurs. An eccentric rear hub would also do, but I am unaware if there are any designed for non single speed systems.

Comment: I haven't got the knees or the balance/skill for SS on trails, so that's a non-starter.  But there are plenty of interesting ideas there (though they sound expensive.  Even casual use round here gets steep. I forgot to start my GPS today but the previous ride hit 26% up.

Comment: You can also have a wider tyre at the front and a narrower one back. Air pressure at the front should also be lower a bit. It's  the front wheel where the traction is needed most. Also, OEM tires coming with new MTBs are known to be of worse quality than aftermarket, even those that are identically branded.

Comment: I'll almost certainly go bigger at the front as it's not as restricted. It's starting to look like the best option is to put the best mud tyre in the 2--2.1" range on the back, even if it doesn't handle as well as I'd like on other stuff (it can't be worse than what I've got) and choose freely at the front.

Comment: Wide range 9 speed cassettes are indeed available now.